# scope issue with function call from object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to execute the fc.text-function via fc.messages.max.call( this );

But I do have the error: TypeError: fc is undefined.

The pure fc.text-function works.

I need some explanation with the scopehandling.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wKPb7/4/)

Here is my Code

```
var fc = {

        methods: { },

        test: function(whatever) {
              console.log("test:", whatever);
            },
        messages: {
            tata: "hello", 
            max: fc.test("Geben Sie bitte einen Wert kleiner oder gleich {0} ein."),
            min: fc.test("Geben Sie bitte einen Wert größer oder gleich {0} ein."),
        },

        otherTest: function() {
                console.log("otherTest works"); 
                fc.test("otherTest");     
                }

   };

fc.test("hello world"); //works
fc.otherTest();         //works also

//fc.messages.max.call( this );
```

How can i fix this ?

I made another jsfiddle where it works fine. but the function is in a different scope.
[one more fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7xT6/3/)

Any explanation?

Comment: What do you want `messages.max` and `messages.min` to become?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the [`this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), you don't need to use  `.call`

Answer (score 1):

The `call()` method is a property of of the [`Function` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

`fc.messages.max` isn't a function. It's value is the return value of `fc.test()`, which is `undefined`.

Comment: If you have a look to my second jsfiddle, there it works. the only different is that the function is in an other scope. Why I can't call them like i did?

Comment: You can't access fc from within fc. When you declare `max: fc.test(` fc wont exist yet, as JS need to compile the entire object before it sets the `fc` variable.

Answer (score 1):

#### From the [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

> The call() method calls a **function** with a given this value and arguments provided individually.

`min: & max:` were not functions so you could not `call()` them.

#### What calls what:

```
var test = function( t ) {
    console.log("one more test: ",t);
};
var fc = {
    
    methods: { },
    
    test: function(whatever) {
        console.log("test:", whatever);
    },
    messages: {
        tata: "hello", 
        max: function() { test("var test") },
        min: function() { fc.test("fc test") }
    },
    
    otherTest: function() {
        console.log("otherTest works"); 
        fc.test("otherTest");     
    }
    
};

fc.test("fc test, hello world"); //calls fc.test
test("var test, hello world"); // calls var test
// fc.otherTest();         //works also

fc.messages.max.call( this ); // call var test
fc.messages.min.call( this ); // calls fc.test
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v7xT6/7/

Comment: thx but this is not what iam looking for. I made on your base another fiddle to demonstrate http://jsfiddle.net/v7xT6/3/. this works fine. but the function is in another scope.

Comment: @hamburger
http://jsfiddle.net/v7xT6/5/ ? this calls the `var test` function. 
Which test function do you want to call the one inside fc, or the one outside?

Comment: @hamburger i've updated the answer to show what calls what heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v7xT6/7/

Comment: thx Rick, I have seen it. In my second jsfiddle it works without declaring max as a function. I'am looking for an explanation, because I do not understand why?

Comment: @hamburger in your second fiddle you are not calling the `max` function,  when you do call it it throws an `undefined` error, because its not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, but i think you can't access `fc.test()` because in `messages` `fc` is not complete yet.

compare:

```
var f = { a: function () { return 1; }, max: f.a() }
> TypeError: Cannot call method 'a' of undefined
```

It says `f` is undefined.

You can't access `f` until the assignment (`var f`) is complete and `f` is defined.